Open Userform by name
I would like to open Userforms using it´s Name without having to hardcode a Select Case-statement for each Userform.
i tried
VBA.UserForms(Integer).Show and
VBA.UserForms(String).Show

first threw error "out of range".
second threw error "type mismatch"
then i tried a for each loop:
Sub Open_UserForm(ByVal UserFormName As String)
Dim Usf As UserForm
For Each Usf in VBA.UserForms
    If Usf.Name = UserFormName Then
        Usf.Show
    End If
Next Usf
End Sub

I tried this with Usf as Object too.
In both cases it skipped the For Each at the first Iteration.
Then i tried it with VBProject and VBComponent:
Workbooks(WorkbookName).VBProject.VBComponents(UserFormName).Show

I tried all these Methods with Modeless too.

This old article from IT veteran C.Pearson seems to address your concerns well: Show any form

Show Userform By Name

Based on Chip Pearson's article suggested by T.M. in your comments.
To test the difference between when the form is loaded (hidden) and when it is not, add a button with the code Me.Hide to hide the form and set the optional ShowMessages argument to True.

Sub ShowUserForm( _
        UserFormName As String, _
        Optional ShowMessages As Variant = False)
    
    Dim obj As Object
    
    For Each obj In VBA.UserForms
        If StrComp(obj.Name, UserFormName, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            If ShowMessages Then MsgBox "Was already loaded.", vbInformation
            obj.Show
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next obj
    
    On Error Resume Next
        Set obj = VBA.UserForms.Add(UserFormName)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If obj Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "User form """ & UserFormName & """ not found!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If ShowMessages Then MsgBox "Was NOT loaded.", vbInformation
    obj.Show
    
End Sub

